# Finding an isomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{12} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a way to find an isomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{12} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_3$?

I figure comparing elements orders might work, but this seems tedious.

I can see that $f(0) = (0,0), f(1) = (1,1), f(2) = (2,1), f(3) = (0,1), ...$ but this leads to a problem when going further.

Comment: Write the order of $(g,h) \in G \oplus H$ in terms of the order of $g$ and the order of $h$. Also your $f$ is not even a homomorphism.

Comment: @OliverG Your list is wrong. $f(0) = (0,0), f(1) = (1,1), f(2) = (2, 2), f(3) = (3, 3) = (3, 0), f(4) = (4, 4) = (0, 1)$ and so on.

Comment: @McFry  How did you get $f(2) = (2,2)$?  If $|2| = 6$ then $|(a,b)| = 6$ iff lcm$(|a|, |b|) = 6$.  And the only $a,b$ that work for $\Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb Z_3$ are $a = 2 \land b = 1,$ or $2$.  How do you know which one works?

Comment: How did I get $f(2) = (2, 2)$? If $f(1) = (1,1)$ then $f(2) = f(1+1) =  f(1) + f(1) = (1, 1) + (1, 1) = (2, 2)$. You seem terribly confused.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
Consider the homomorphism
$$
\Z\longrightarrow \Z/3\Z\oplus \Z/4\Z,\quad x \longmapsto (x\bmod 3, x\bmod 4).
$$
It is clear that the kernel is just $12\Z$, because if $x\equiv 0\mod 3$ and $x\equiv 0\mod 4$ then $x$ is divisible by $3$ and $4$ and thus by $12$, i. e. $x\equiv 0\mod 12$.

This gives an injective homomorphism $\Z/12\Z\rightarrow \Z/3\Z\oplus \Z/4\Z$. Since both groups have the same cardinality, it follows that this is also an isomorphism.

This is nothing but the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: I haven't come across quotients, kernals, homomorphisms, or the Chinese remainder theorem yet in my book, is there a way to do this without using those theorems?

Comment: If you don't know homomorphisms, how do you know about isomorphisms? Anyway, I didn't use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I proved it for this special case.
You can directly write down the map $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ given above (to avoid taking the quotient) and show that it is well defined and a homomorphism. Then it suffices to show injectivity which is the same argument as above.

Comment: I haven't come across the symbols $\Bbb Z / 12 \Bbb Z$ in the book I'm reading yet either.

Comment: @OliverG It's the same thing as $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ (I personally prefer $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ because the latter also denotes the $p$-adics)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with homomorphisms and kernals in your proof, is there a way to explain this without referencing them?

Comment: There is no way to do it without homomorphisms. If you want to show that two groups are isomorphic, you have to define an isomorphism between them. And an isomorphism is a homomorphism. I already told you how to prove your statement without kernels in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple: consider the homomorphism $\begin{aligned}[t]\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z,\\
n&\longmapsto (x\bmod3,x\bmod4).\end{aligned}$

The kernel of this homomorphism is $3\mathbf Z\cap 4\mathbf Z=12\mathbf Z$, hence it factors through an injective homomorphism $\mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$.

Furthemore, these homorphisms are surjective, because of *Bézout's identity*, so that the latter injectice homomorphism is indeed an isomorphism.

Explicitly, since a $Bézout's relation$ between $3$ and $4$ is just $4-3=1$, the reverse isomorphism is given by:
$$(x\bmod3, y\bmod 4)\longmapsto 4x-3y\bmod 12.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed map works just fine:

Let $\tilde{\varphi} \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_3 \otimes \mathbb{Z}_4$ be the unique group homomorphism with $\tilde{\varphi}(1) = (1,1)$.

This map is surjective because $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ is generated by the two elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, for which we have $(1,0) = \tilde{\varphi}(4) \in \operatorname{im} \tilde{\varphi}$ and $(0,1) = \tilde{\varphi}(9) \in \operatorname{im} \tilde{\varphi}$.

An element $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is in the kernel of $\tilde{\varphi}$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of both $3$ and $4$, which is equivalent to $n$ being a multiple of $12$.
Therefore $\ker \tilde{\varphi} = 12\mathbb{Z}$.

It follows that $\tilde{\varphi}$ factors through an isomorphism of groups
$\varphi \colon \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$, which is uniquely determined by $\varphi(1) = (1,1)$.

---

**EDIT:**

One can also replace the use of kernel and quotient by the underlying explicit calculations:

If $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $[n]_{12} = [m]_{12}$ then $n = m + 12k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
It follows that
$$
    [n]_{3}
  = [m + 12k]_3
  = [m]_3 + [12k]_3
  = [m]_3 + [0]_3
  = [m + 0]_3
  = [m]_3
$$
and similarly $[n]_4 = [m]_4$ (here we use that $12$ is a multiple of both $3$ and $4$).
Therefore the map
$$
  \varphi \colon \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4,
  \quad
  [n]_{12} \mapsto ([n]_3, [n]_4)
$$
is well-defined.
It is a group homomorphism, because for all $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have
\begin{align*}
    \varphi([n]_{12} + [m]_{12})
  &= \varphi([n+m]_{12})
   = ([n+m]_3, [n+m]_4)
   = ([n]_3 + [m]_3, [n]_4 + [m]_4) \\
  &= ([n]_3, [n]_4) + ([m]_3, [m]_4)
   = \varphi([n]_{12}) + \varphi([m]_{12}).
\end{align*}

Because $\varphi([4]_{12}) = ([1]_3, [0]_4)$ and $\varphi([9]_{12}) = ([0]_3, [1]_4)$ it follows as above that $\varphi$ is surjective; more explicitely one has
$$
  \varphi([4n + 9m]_{12}) = ([n]_3, [m]_4)
  \quad
  \text{for all $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$}.
$$

There are now two ways to see that $\varphi$ is injective:

One quick way is to notice that $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ have the same amout of elements (namely $12$), so the surjectivity of $\varphi$ is equivalent to its injectivity.

Another way is to pick $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\varphi([n]_{12}) = \varphi([m]_{12})$ and show that $[n]_{12} = [m]_{12}$:
That $\varphi([n]_{12}) = \varphi([m]_{12})$ is equivalent to $[n]_3 = [m]_3$ and $[n]_4 = [m]_4$, i.e. $[n-m]_3 = 0$ and $[n-m]_4 = 0$.
This means that $n-m$ is both a multiple of $3$ and $4$, and therefore a multiple of $12$ (here we use that $12$ is the least common multiple of $3$ and $4$).
Hence $[n-m]_{12} = 0$ and thus $[n]_{12} = [m]_{12}$.

Comment: I haven't come across the term group homomorphism or kernel in the book I'm reading, is there a way to do this without referring to those?

Comment: And if it works, how do you define $f(4)$?  Since $f(4) = f(3)f(1) \land f(2)f(2)$  so $f(4) = (1,2) \land (0,2)$ ?  I'm not sure which one would work.

Comment: @OliverG If $f(1) = (1, 1)$ and $f(3) = (3, 3) = (3, 0)$, then $f(4) = f(3)f(1)$ means $f(4) = (3, 0) + (1, 1) = (4, 1) = (0, 1)$.

Comment: @OliverG: I added another solutions, which shows the underlying calculations.

Comment: What does $[n]_{12}$ mean?  I'm also unfamiliar with group homomorphisms.